# How to make Url helper work when on routed page?

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-routing

I have a url which routes to a custom module. I have added this line in my Bootstrap.php

```
$router->addRoute('forum-board', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        'forum-board', array('module' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'forumdisplay')
    ));
```

Routes are working fine!

But, in views of forumdisplay when I call:

```
<a href="<?= $this->url( array ( 'module' => 'admin', 
                'controller'=> 'users', 'action' => 'resetpass',
                'userid'=>$userid)); ?>">Reset</a>
```

it does not render URL.

When I opened the same page as:

```
http://zfProj12.local/admin/users/forumdisplay
```

it rendered correct urls but, on routing them, it doesn't i.e. as

```
http://zfProj12.local/forum-board
```

Any fixes?

Comment: By "it does not render URL" you mean the actual output is "" (empty)? What is the expected correct output?

Comment: The output is expected to /admin/users/resetpass/userid/xxxx as a URL but, it just shows /forum-board/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want the `url()` view-helper to render according to your defined route, you reference the route by name as (in a view script, for example):

```
<a href="<?= $this->url(array('userid' => 'myuserid'), 'forum-board', true) ?>">Forum</a>
```

**Update**

Your invocation of the url helper suggests that you want the route to accept a userid param, but the route definition itself has no placeholder for it. Perhaps the route should be defined as:

```
$router->addRoute('forum-board', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'forum-board/:userid', array(
         'module' => 'admin', 
         'controller' => 'users', 
         'action' => 'forumdisplay',
     )
));
```

Then when you invoke the url helper with a value for `userid`, that value will get inserted into the generated url.

Comment: Well, there seems to be some conflict. Your invocation of the url helper suggests that you want the route to accept a `userid` param, but the route definition itself has no placeholder for it. Updating the answer to show a more complete example.